# Linux folder change auto notification

Tags: linux, notifications

Is there a way that I can programmatically figure out whether a particular file with certain characteristics is being added into say the linux /tmp folder. All I need to create, is a small script that is automatically called every time a new file is added in the tmp folder.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These links might be helpful: [Inotify](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inotify) and [Inotify-tools](https://github.com/rvoicilas/inotify-tools/).

Comment: Actually I knew these options, I was looking for a simpler mechanism, but I think this should be the way to go.

Comment: There is dnotify, which should fit your requirements. Not to be confused with the obsolete kernel subsystem, dnotify is also a program to execute commands when directories change. Searching for "man 5 dnotify" should give you more information.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`entr` tool](http://entrproject.org/) to do that in the following way:

```
while true; do find /tmp/ | entr -d ./temp_changed.sh; done
```

A directory watch option (`-d`) reacts to events when a new file is added to a directory.